# Using a PagedList with Join two model in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller

I Select some filed from database with below code:

```
    var _Users = (from s in db.Users
                 from ur in s.Roles
                 join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                 select new
                 {
                     s.Id,
                     s.Email,
                     s.FirstName,
                     s.LastName,
                     Name = s.UserName,
                     Role = r.Name,
                 });
```

and send result to view:

```
return View("Index", _Users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

in the view:

```
@using PagedList.Mvc
@model PagedList.IPagedList<FinalKaminet.Models.ApplicationUser>
```

But i got this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'PagedList.PagedList`1[<>f__AnonymousType10`6[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'PagedList.IPagedList`1[FinalKaminet.Models.ApplicationUser]'.

what is wrong?

Comment: The error is self explanatory - you view expects `@model PagedList.IPagedList<.ApplicationUser>` but you passing it an anonymous object.

Comment: How can i correct my code?

Comment: Create a view model with the properties you want and use `select new MyViewModel { ...` and change the view to `@model PagedList<MyViewModel>`

Comment: ok, thanks, I do this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in select you are not defining type what you are passing to view change it to     `select new ApplicationUser`

```
 var _Users = (from s in db.Users
                 from ur in s.Roles
                 join r in db.Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                 select new MyViewModel 
                 {
                    firstproperty = s.Id,//initialize every property like this
                     s.Email,
                     s.FirstName,
                     s.LastName,
                     Name = s.UserName,
                     Role = r.Name,
                 }).ToList();//call to List

class MyViewModel 
{
  //define properties you needto show in view
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention, i got  `Cannot iniatialize type 'ApplicationUser' with a collection initialize because it does not implement 'Sysytem.Collections.IEnumerable'` error whit this code.

Comment: Create one View model with all properties u need to show